# Manually trigger timer trigger azure function and know when it finished running?

Tags: azure-functions, ready-api

Background:
I have a timer triggered azure function and it will write to DB. In my automation testing (Ready-API from smartBear), after I manually triggered the timer function, I have another step to query the DB to assert the record got inserted.

Problem:
When manually invoking the timer function, it will respond back with 202 immediately. This will tell my automation to continue to the next step ("query DB") without wait the function to be executed. So the "query DB" step will fail from time to time because of the racing problem.

Question:
I don't want to add "delay" in between those test steps because sometimes the function is "cold start" which will take way longer for it to be executed. Wondering are there anyways to know for sure a timer-triggered function finished running?